# How to identify a dynamically changing index in QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp

I am trying to click an element using below code. There i want to pass "index" value from a variable. Is there any way to do it?

```
Browser("Home Page").Page("Account Search").WebElement("innertext:=Request","index:=5","html tag:=A").Click
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty simple.

```
Dim i
i = 5

Browser("Home Page").Page("Account Search").WebElement("innertext:=Request","index:=" & i,"html tag:=A").Click
```

Comment: Glad to help... :)